# android: string format specify bold

Tags: android

I have a string defined in `string.xml` like

```
<string name="eventtitle">Title: %1$s </string>
```

which is formatted using `string.format` . How to define the string to get only the **Titel: as Bold.**

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to style your string in the TextView in which in is displayed. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but that is incorrect @bvd.  Strings can be styled in the string.xml as per
"You can add styling to your strings with HTML markup..."
via http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 22):

You can do it like,

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Title</b>: Text"));
```

If you have text in dynamic way..

And to define formatings in Strings.xml you can do like,

```
<string name="text1">This text uses <b>bold</b> and <i>italics</i> 
by using inline tags such as <b> within the string file.</string>
```

see **[This Link](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html)**

Comment: `Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated now

Comment: Where did you find that it's deprecated? They added new methods in API 24.

Answer (score 12):

Now, it is reasonably supported by [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

you can define the string in xml as `<string name="text_to_show">Hey &lt;b>This is in bold&lt;/b>`

Then in code, use this to convert to CharSequence and then use it for e.g in TextView

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.text-to_show);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
textview.setText(styledText);
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, many of the answers are obsolete. After researching by myself, what I've found out that the best answer is one by @Wahib. Here's the improved version:

Define the string resource as a:

```
<string name="styled_text">Hey, &lt;b>this is bold&lt;/b> text</string>
```

Use the resource like this:

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.styled_text);
CharSequence styledText = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
textview.setText(styledText);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTML markup like `"<b>BOLD</b> other text ..."`.
See [this Google resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tfaerial=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aerial.ttf");
Typeface tfTradeGothicLight=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TradeGothic-Light.OTF");

String strt_title_desc=this.getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle);
```

`int upto=strt_title_desc.indexOf(":");` //of you can specify  5

```
 if (strt_title_desc!=null)
    {
        aboutAuthTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        aboutAuthTV.setLineSpacing(1.2f, 1.5f);
        aboutAuthTV.setTextSize(23);
    SpannableString SS = new SpannableString(strt_title_desc);
    SS. setSpan ( new StyleSpan(tfTradeGothicLight.getStyle()), 0, upto,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    SS. setSpan ( new StyleSpan(tfaerial.getStyle()), upto, strt_dialog_desc.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    yourtextView.setText(SS);
}
```

// this for changing the font size, style and colors

```
String str="<font size =\"20\"><B>Bold</B> <br/> Then Normal Text<br/>
                         <i>Then Italic</i> </font>" +
                       "<br/> <font color=\"green\" >this is simple sentence </font>" +
                       "<br/><br/><br/><br/><a>this is simple sentence</a>";
      Spanned strHtml= Html.fromHtml(str);

       TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
       tv.setText(strHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, it is reasonably supported by [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071637/1016544).

I have already given answer to this [how to add styling within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071637/1016544)

Comment: You answered the same question twice - look up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071552/2004186