# How do I set up localization for Indian regional languages in Android emulator?

Tags: android, localization, android-emulator, locale

I would like to set my emulator locale to some custom locale for Indian regional languages like Tamil or Kanada or telugu.

Comment: you want support multiple language for your application? or totally change android phone language?

Comment: @Dinesh I want to support kanada language in my app.

Comment: @dinesh I want to change the locale in my phone similar to  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/ but without the need of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must download your language font file(.ttf). after,import font file in your project assets folder create folder fonts and paste your font file(.ttf) to folder fonts.
after following instructions in below link for stack overflow post :

[Android Tamil font between english word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635516/android-tamil-font-between-english-word)

(or)

Refer this document

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

iso code for all languages link below

http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm

Welcome...!

Answer (score 3):

It is my fault not clearly understanding android documentation link given below 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

For others sake,

Creating and using a custom locale is for developers to test localization apps in android emulator.There are two ways to create custom locale for more see above link.

```
* Use the Custom Locale application, which is accessible from the Application tab. (After you create a custom locale, switch to it by pressing and holding the locale name.) In my case I given te_IN for telugu(Indian) locale. 
* Change to a custom locale from the adb shell
```

I am just confused by checking custom locale app in device.

Also, Right now there is no default locale support for Indian regional languages except for Hindi, for which code is hi_IN, that too in Android 4.0.3. So even though we set Custom locale to telugu Indian i.e te_IN, Android system will not identify telugu fonts. Any suggestions on this? I want this on Android 2.2 version.