# set custom font through xml

Tags: android, xml, fonts

how can i set a font, whose ttf resides in my `assets` folder through xml? 
I know [how to do that programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694163/custom-font-on-android) but how can you do that via xml? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot do it using XML directly, however you can extend `TextView` and set a default font.

```
package com.nannu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NanTV extends TextView{

    private Context c;
    public NanTV(Context c) {
        super(c);
        this.c = c;
        Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                "font/yourfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tfs);

    }
    public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.c = context;
        Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                "font/yourfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tfs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.c = context;
        Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                "font/yourfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tfs);

    }


}
```

And in your layout use new `TextView`

```
<com.nannu.NanTV
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 

        />
```

I am posting this from my prev answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239305/1166537

Answer (score 3):

If you create your own `TextView` derivation, you could add an XML-attribute that the class handles the programmatical way. That way, you specify a certain font and it'll be set runtime, but you do it via XML. :)

Otherwise, there's no known way to achieve the requested behaviour.

Comment: that sounds good, can you give an example? I don't think a lot of people thought about doing this.

Comment: If you check iNan's example below, it would be along that way (just adding custom attributes & getting them via ``AttributeSet attrs``). My eclipse is broken so I can't quite help you out with the actual code right now. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing your custom TextView, otherwise you will have to set it programmatically. For more details see this [link](http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/custom-fonts-in-android-widgets)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a library to solve this problem here: http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/03/15/custom-fonts-in-android-widgets.html

You extend a TextView and set the name of the typeface in the xml.  There is a downloadable sample.

Answer (score 0):

[You can include custom fonts under assets/fonts and then using the code from https://github.com/browep/AndroidCustomFontWidgets/](https://github.com/browep/AndroidCustomFontWidgets/)

you can specify the font in your XML, e.g.

```
<com.github.browep.customfonts.view.FontableTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is in a custom font"
        app:font="MyFont-Bold.otf" />
```

The code supports FontableTextView and FontableButton, but it's quite easy to extend to support other widget types if you require.