# set custom font through xml is not working in some devices

Tags: android, custom-font, android-fonts

By using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471778/3182144) 
i extend TextView and set my custom font(ComicSansMS.ttf) its working fine in android kitkat 4.4 but in ics(micromax A89) font is not applied.

This code works fine in android kitkat 4.4 but not in ics(micromax A89)-   it not increase my heap memory size and my app not get crashed

```
<com.example.sample.setFont
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        />
```

but when i set `app:fontName="ComicSansMS.ttf"` works fine in ics(micromax A89) but it increase my heap memory size and my app gets crashed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely dup of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901930/memory-leaks-with-custom-font-for-set-custom-font

Comment: thanks peterson...increase my heap memory size is gone but font is not applied in ics(micromax A89).

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at https://github.com/rupehshsasne/YetAnotherTextView library.