# How can i give custom font in XML itself through asset folder Font .ttf file?

Tags: android, custom-font, font-family, android-typeface

I want to work with custom font for my app,so I need to get custom font from asset folder,and initialize that as a property in xml file.

```
android:fontFamily="fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf"
```

I just tried this but ,xml won't reflect it.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

-Store **fontname.ttf** to **fonts** directory inside **assets** directory.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/fontname.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Hope this will be helpful...thanks

Comment: thankq sir,but Is any chance to give typaface in XML itself,by that i need to reduce my code complexity

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 //create instance
 Typeface tf;

 //initialize it
 tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/light.TTF");

 //then set it on textview ,buttons ...
 duration.setTypeface(tf);

 //if you dont have asseste folder create like this in image!
```

Comment: thankq sir,but Is any chance to give typaface in XML itself,by that i need to reduce my code complexity

Comment: for that purpose you have to create your class ......this might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471640/set-custom-font-through-xml]