# Regional Language font (Gurumukhi or Punjabi) is not working in version higer than 2.2

Tags: android, fonts

I am using the gurumukhi(Punjabi) font in my application. It is working fine in the lower version but not in the higher versions. 
I am doing this way

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"bulara_5.ttf");
                      Book_Data.setTypeface(tf);     
                      Book_Data.setText( XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Pun"));
```

Can anyone help me. How can i make it so it support the higher version as well. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in doing this, i check it and it's work for me at android 4.

May be you don't change the language of program and it's the reason of your problem. see this for set language of your application :

- [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android/9173571#9173571)

And your can see this question for your problem :

- [I want to show the Reginonal language(Gurumukhi) in my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238909/i-want-to-show-the-reginonal-languagegurumukhi-font-in-my-android-app)

And check the name of font("bulara_5.ttf") in your assets and don't be in a folder of assets. the name must be bulara_5.ttf and it does not be something like this bulara_5.TTF.

Comment: Yes you are right i have made a very silly mistake. Thanks for your response.