# How to convert punjabi Asees to Arial Unicode MS

Tags: android, excel, ms-word

I have punjabi text in excel, how to copy punjabi text from excel to word or notepad or android strings.xml file

Comment: You can view this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11240506/3940292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below link is to convert punjabi Asees to Arial Unicode MS

http://www.punjabiconverter.com/index.php?fln=Asees&tln=Arial%20Unicode%20MS