# Create an App to support Local Language with Unicode supportedfont

Tags: android, fonts

I am new to android programming.I learned some basic stuffs from the youtube tutorial videos.I want to create an app for my blog. The app should act as a web browser and display the content of my blog as such.But the problem is I used to write my blog in a local Indian language.So I want my app to support my local language font which is a Unicode supported font.Is it possible to make my app to support such local font.Please help me?Sorry for my poor english!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom fonts for your Android Application,

For this, you need to use `Typeface` and also you need to have knowledge of Character Mapping of your font.

Following likns will help you,

- [how to set custom locale for indian regional languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943811/how-to-set-custom-locale-for-indian-regional-languages-in-android-emulator)
- [Can I embed a custom font in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424165/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-android-application)
- [Android development using custom fonts](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/)
- [Customize Android Fonts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

Comment: Thanks.. but am using a Webview to load my website.Is it possible set font for webview?

Comment: do you want to use a font for the webview, which loads all the websites in your default font.

Comment: sir.. actually my aim is to create a an app with a webview which will automatically load my blog. I used loadUrl() method to load my blog by giving its url as arguments.But my blog is not in English. Its in Malayalam which is an Indian language.I used a unicod fond Meera.ttf. I want set my webView font to meera.ttf so that it can display the content of blog correctly. Is it possible set font for webView

Comment: why do you want to set a font for web view. It can automatically load the site in malyalam font, if the device supports the malyalam font.

Comment: device support malayalam font.. but not in correct ways..some characters are not in correct format.But while using some android browsers like opera and ucweb it showed all the malayalam fonts in correct font.Can I make my webview just like that.?