# speak with TTS such as Hindi

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

In my application , I wish to know if there is any tts engine that can read hindi text .
my code

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

unfortunately Hindi is not supported by Android. 
See the list of Locales supported below

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html
```

How will i do the hindi locale any help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: check the below link
[Localization  in android for indian regional languages][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943811/how-to-set-custom-locale-for-indian-regional-languages-in-android-emulator

Comment: @Praveena_Pinki he want how to add Hindi TTS(Test to speech in hindi locale) As there is no support from google He is expecting any other 3rd party libs.

Comment: yes padma kumar you are right

Answer (score 12):

Hindi is supported by Android -- it is just that there isn't a `Locale` constant for it.

If you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes, then `hi` is the ISO 639-1 code for Hindi. Also note that Android/Java may also use the ISO 39-3 code which for Hindi is `hin`.

Therefore, you need to use either:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hi"));
```

or:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hin"));
```

You will also need to use a text-to-speech synthesiser that supports Hindi, otherwise you will get a "language not supported" error. The eSpeak text to speech synthesiser supports Hindi.

I have a port of eSpeak for Android 4.0 and later [1]/[2] for £0.99. This has many improvements and bug fixes over the eyes free port and is kept up-to-date with the latest eSpeak releases.

1. http://reecedunn.co.uk/espeak-for-android
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reecedunn.espeak

Comment: @reece Hi sir, can please help me for Kannada Language.

Comment: @reece i tried (tts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("kan")); like this but not woking

Comment: pronunciation is very different.How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to convert Krutidev font to Unicode:  [krutidevtounicode](https://pub.dev/packages/krutidevtounicode/)
and then you can give the text to tts for speaking it will speak in hindi and if not then install hindi version of tts in mobile/emulator.

```
var text = KrutidevToUnicode.convertToUnicode("gsyks oYMZ");
FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
await flutterTts.speak(text);
```