# How to text to speech in hindi android?

Tags: android

I want to speech the words in Hindi in my application. Following this link:
[www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/)

but there in availability of Hindi Locale.
How can I make the set up for Hindi translations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [speak with TTS such as Hindi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605247/speak-with-tts-such-as-hindi)

Comment: refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751865/1529129)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a change while setting language.

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            t1.setLanguage(new Locale("hin")); // Setting Hindi language
        }
    }
});
```

You can set the language as shown in the code above. That worked for me.