# How to create android UI in Hindi?

Tags: android, utf-8, localization, android-resources

I am developing an app where it need to supported in two languages (English & Hindi). I am familiar in designing in English but i don't have any idea regarding  how to create UI in Hindi.

Can anyone please help me how to create android UI in Hindi......?
I want the following XML file in Hindi means in the place of Name & Password as per below image, i need to get Hindi words.. but i kept Hindi text means it is showing boxes in place of username & password. As you can find below button. created two dynamic textview. English text is displaying exactly but coming to Hindi text displaying boxes.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutbase"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:text="Username"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:text="नमस्ते"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

output is displaying boxes as per below image

[image]
   [image]

Comment: You need to target Android 2.3 and up. Hindi fonts should be accessible then.

Comment: ya, i am using 2.3 but don't know how to display hindi fonts.

Comment: According to this bug report it is not functional on every 2.3 device: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4153 It should work with ICS. This thread describes how to use your own font in your app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download .ttf(true type font)file for hindi and create folder name as fonts in your project asset folder and paste hindi_font_file.ttf file in your asset under fonts folder and refer and set font face in your textview like below code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hindi_font_file.ttf");               
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
tv.setText("हिंदी");
```

Now hindi text display on your ui for more details try to follow instructions below post

[Android Tamil font between english word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635516/android-tamil-font-between-english-word)

and here is [link](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=hindi%20true%20type%20fonts%20free%20download&oq=hindi%20true%20ty&gs_l=hp.11.2.0i10j0i30l3.0.0.5.1228.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.oipWElBjTOI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e0d56e20f3999d57&biw=1360&bih=667&pf=p&pdl=300) for download hindi ttf file

Comment: this is when creating dynamic view. Is there any way how to display hindi view from our XML files as i want to create my UI in XML & not as dynamic UI...

Comment: @code_finder apply your textview like TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id_from_xml);!

Comment: can you please elaborate. here "R.id.your_textview_id_from_xml" from here textview_id is textview id as per xml. Then what is "from_xml" here. didn't got it. can you please explain it

Comment: i am binding textview in java file like this.... TextView xmltxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); is the one you are saying about.

Comment: as per my above xml it is still displaying in boxes only. not displaying hindi text...

Comment: Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hindi_font_file.ttf");               
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
tv.setText("हिंदी")

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what you need is [Android-Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html), Which support both languages English and Hindi.

Look at this tutorial [Android-Application-Localization](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/).

Comment: without using localization i need to run it. based on users choice if he selects hindi version means all app needs to be visible in hindi. that is the main criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Also, be aware that HTC does not support Hindi font display

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem by myself. I have downloaded **"mangal.ttf"** (hindi font supported file) & copied it in fonts folder created in assets folder.

Modified my java code as

Main.java

```
    TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
    tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mangal.ttf"));
    tv1.setText("इस अंग्रेज़ी हिन्दी अंग्रेज़ी शब्दकोश में आप आसानी से हिन्दी और अंग्रेज़ी शब्दों के अर्थ ढूंढ सकते हैं। नवम्बर ");
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    layout.addView(tv1);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Post a new question for the followup question.

Answer (score 0):

The static text that you display (Username, Password) etc need to be localized by supplying appropriate strings using Android's resources framework. Be aware about the platform version that you target. I don't recollect exactly what version of Android introduced Hindi support, but you can look it up in the release notes of each platform version.

Finally, if you want to accept user input in Hindi you again need to be aware of the platform version. You can go to **Settings** -> **Language and Input**; then the "Preferences" icon for **Android Keyboard (AOSP)** --> **Input Languages**. If you see Hindi in the list there, your platform should support Hindi input. However, I am not sure of device manufacturer support in this space so you should probably test on real devices.