# wants to have multiple text display styles in a single textview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles

I am working on an android app i want to know how i can make few words in bold regular and few in italic for example i have a textview with a text HELLOO now I want to display the text like this in a text view

**HELL***OO*

please tell me how to achieve this through styles in android??

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8471977/1012284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, you have a TextView namely **etx**, use the following code:

---

```
 final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("HELLOO");

        final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
        final StyleSpan iss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC);Span to make text italic
        sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold 
        sb.setSpan(iss, 4, 6, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make last 2 characters Italic
        etx.setText(sb);
```

---

The main advantage of using this approach is that you can format text dynamically.

Comment: When you use SpannableStringBuilder you have to set the text with this TextView method :
setText(int resid, TextView.BufferType type)

so your code must be :
etx.setText(sb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Comment: @GBouerat I think you are talking about `setText (CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)` not `setText (int resid, TextView.BufferType type)`. I always get the perfect result with `setText (CharSequence text)` method. So, can you please kindly explain why this approach shouldn't be used and advantage of above methods.

Comment: what if i dont know the length of text to be styled, but i want the whole text to be styled

Comment: @AnoopssGolden text length can be easily obtained using length() method.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. Its a large activiy, contains thousands of views. The view with this kind of styling is being inflated every time. so i want to minimize the processing.

Comment: @AnoopssGolden then you can use style & android:textStyle or a custom textview class and use setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD...
Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android/3166865#3166865

Comment: @ImranRana can u pls help me lets say i have text :  you are followed by a person ..... so i have to bold and red in color everytime .... person .... and as well depending on condition all texts other than person should be black and normal or black and bold  ?how will i do this ? but i cant give hardcoded number like 10 -15   index numbers  this is the text i m recicving from server i just have to  find string if found then set in red and bold and all other text should be black and normal

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` is deprecated. use `<strong>` and `<em>` instead of `<i>`.

```
text1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong>bold text</strong> normal text <em>italic text</em> "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have String in strings.xml then.

```
<string name="startup"><b><i>HELL</i></b><i>oo</i></string>
```

You can use HTML Tags Here inside `<string> </string>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it bold use the b tag.If you want it to be italic use i tag.If u want to make a word bold or italic put that single word inside the tag.

```
 <resources> 
<string name="register"> <u><b><i>SignUp</i></b></u> </string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String text="<html>"+"<b>"+"Hell"+"</b>"+"<i>"+"oo"+"</i>"+"</html>";
```