# How to make text in a list BOLD when clicked ?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change a TextView's style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime)

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listproducts"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#C8C8C8"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
</ListView>
```

This is the code for the list i'm using. And below is the code for the text i want in my list.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/productname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    />
```

The ' android:selectAllOnFocus ' doesn't seem to work with textview, it does for a button. 
what should i do ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630440/how-to-change-a-textviews-style-at-runtime) you go (Java code. Scroll to first answer, second code part)

Comment: Thank you. i hope it will work now!

Comment: nice solution ........... you can also check the list selector I am not sure but I think that also have this option...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365893/how-to-change-color-of-android-list-item-on-click-or-selection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789661/android-relativelayout-change-color-onclick

Comment: For changing style in TextView you can also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649398/wants-to-have-multiple-text-display-styles-in-a-single-textview/10654254#10654254)